# TopView is not accessible from presented view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a view which is added to UIApplication.keyWindow to make it visible to all viewControllers. But this view is not accessible when some controller is presented and over it another controller is presented. The above said view is not accessible from second presented controller.

I am using this code UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.addSubView(myView).

So how can i made my view accessible from here.

I have shared two images here. One is normal and another one view debugging.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNGU4.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaHGG.png)

Comment: Try `view.bringSubview(toFront: myView)`

Comment: I tried but that is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by putting the code UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.addSubView(myView) in viewDidAppear and this resolved the above issue.